# Order of sum of first numbers powered to a complex or limit resolution

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is there any approach to solve:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}{n^s}$$

where $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ 0<\Re(s) < 1$?

Actually I don't need an exact result but just coefficient of the higher exponent, or more explicitly to calculate the next limit:

$$\lim_{N->\infty}{\frac{ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N\over 2}{{(n+\frac{N}{2})}^s} }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N\over 2}{n^s}}}$$

I have an idea on how to proceed for natural exponents, but I don't know how to proceed for $s$ complex.

Comment: Is this inspired by the series from the Riemann zeta function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z}$, convergent for $\Re(z)>1$, where your $s=-z$ has the range $0<\Re(s)<1$ corresponding to $-1<\Re(z)<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the [Euler—Maclaurin formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#i) still works, although I'm not totally sure about the estimate of the remainder term:
$$f(N)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{k=1}^N k^s= \tfrac{N^{1+s}-1^{1+s}}{1+s} +\tfrac{N^s+1^s}{2} +O(1)$$
Then
$$\frac{f(2N)-f(N)}{f(N)}=2^{1+s}-1+o(1)\text{.}$$

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. I will try to get a more accurate approach for the error term, since my application requires it, but it is exactly what I required.